# Loop after input of NULL value in simple C shell

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to write a simple C shell. My problem is that I have written the program so that when the user enters a NULL value I've got the shell to exit and stop running. However after using different shells i've realised that the shell continues to loop. Is there anyway to fix this without having to rewrite my code? I'm still quite a novice to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_CMD_SIZE 512

 int getPath(){
        printf("PATH = %s\n", getenv("PATH"));
        return 0;
 }

 int setPath(char* arg){
        setenv("PATH", arg, 1);
        return 0;
 }

 int setwd() {
char *arg;
arg = getenv("HOME");
chdir(arg);
return 0;
}

int main()
{
        char buff[MAX_CMD_SIZE]; //buff used to hold commands the user will type in
        char *defaultPath = getenv("PATH");
        char *args[50] = {NULL};
        char *arg;
        int i;
        pid_t pid;

        setwd();
        while(1){
                printf(">");
                if (fgets(buff, MAX_CMD_SIZE, stdin) == NULL) { //Will exit if no value is typed on pressing enter
                        setPath(defaultPath);
                        getPath();
                        exit(0);
                } 

                arg = strtok(buff, " <|>\n\t");
                i = 0;
                if (arg == NULL) return -1;

                while (arg != NULL){
                        printf("%s\n", arg);
                        args[i] = arg;
                        arg = strtok(NULL, " <|>\n\t");
                        i++;
                }

                if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0 && !feof(stdin)){ //Will exit if input is equal to "exit" or ctrl + d
                        setPath(defaultPath);
                        getPath();
                        exit(0);
                }

            else {
                    pid = fork();
                    if (pid < 0){ //Error checking
                            fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed\n");
                    } else if (pid == 0){ //This is the child procsess
                            execvp(args[0], args);
                            exit(-1);
                    } else { //Parent Process
                        wait(NULL); // Parent will wait for child to complete
                    }
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: how are they supposed to enter a NULL value?

Comment: Do you mean *empty string* by saying "NULL value"?

Comment: Presumably they mean if `fgets` returns NULL, which indicates EOF or a read error.

Comment: No, there's no way to change that without having to rewrite your code. :) Honest.

Comment: you mean if use not enter any string then it must exit right? so what's wrong hit `ENTER` you will be out of that.

Comment: It works fine here. If I just press Enter the program exits because of the test `if (arg == NULL) return -1;` because `arg` will be NULL if `strtok` find no more tokens, which is the case if the string `buff` is empty.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: According to the question, that's the current, undesired behavior.  He wants it to continue looping on empty input (and presumably process an `exit` command to actually terminate)

Comment: @BenVoigt: ok, the question is actually not very clear. If you are right then replacing `if (arg == NULL) return -1;` by `if (arg == NULL) continue ;` does the job.

Comment: `fork` + `execvp`, wouldn't that be a fork-bomb?